# How to run Winforms with BackgroundService and Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, background-service

I'm trying to start a **BackgroundService** assigned to a **services.HostedService** of an **IHostBuilder**.

**IHostBuilder** definition:

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<LicenseControl>();

                services.AddTransient<Database>();
                services.AddTransient<CoreLicense>();

                services.AddSingleton<FormSelector>();

                services.AddTransient<ClienteForm>();
                services.AddTransient<GastoForm>();
                services.AddTransient<IngredienteForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ProdutoForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ReceitaForm>();
                services.AddTransient<RelatorioForm>();
                services.AddTransient<VendaForm>();
                services.AddTransient<MainForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ConfiguracoesForm>();
                services.AddTransient<UsuarioForm>();

                services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationForm>();
                
                services.AddScoped<IBridgeRepository, BridgeRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IGastoRepository, GastoRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IIBGERepository, IBGERepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IIngredienteRepository, IngredienteRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IProdutoRepository, ProdutoRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IReceitaRepository, ReceitaRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IVendaRepository, VendaRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();

                services.AddLogging(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddFilter("NToastNotify", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddConsole();
                }
                );
            });
    }
```

but the only possible way I found to start the **HostedService** is by running this:

```
await CreateHostBuilder().Build().RunAsync();
```

Finally, the problem happens because on this approach, the thread locks on that line and don't let me run the common block code to start the **Form** itself:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

The same happens if I run the **Form** first, the thread'd lock on that line and wouldn't let me call the **RunAsync** of **HostBuilder**.

I also tried to declare all **HostBuilder** scope on the Form class and start the **BackgroundService** on it's constructor, but then I wouldn't be able to run the Async method on a ctor.

What I'm currently trying (but no success yet) is to call the **Form** without the **Application.Run** (and still don't know all the side effects by doing this) so I can run the **HostBuilder** next.

My entire **Program** class now:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);            

        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();

        host.Services.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationForm>().Show();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<LicenseControl>();

                services.AddTransient<Database>();
                services.AddTransient<CoreLicense>();

                services.AddSingleton<FormSelector>();

                services.AddTransient<ClienteForm>();
                services.AddTransient<GastoForm>();
                services.AddTransient<IngredienteForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ProdutoForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ReceitaForm>();
                services.AddTransient<RelatorioForm>();
                services.AddTransient<VendaForm>();
                services.AddTransient<MainForm>();
                services.AddTransient<ConfiguracoesForm>();
                services.AddTransient<UsuarioForm>();

                services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationForm>();
                
                services.AddScoped<IBridgeRepository, BridgeRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IGastoRepository, GastoRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IIBGERepository, IBGERepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IIngredienteRepository, IngredienteRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IProdutoRepository, ProdutoRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IReceitaRepository, ReceitaRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IVendaRepository, VendaRepository>();
                services.AddScoped<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();

                services.AddLogging(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddFilter("NToastNotify", LogLevel.Warning)
                           .AddConsole();
                }
                );
            });
    }
}
```

What'd be the workaround for this considering .NET 5 and ignoring BackgroundWorker component?

Comment: Make another hosted service to invoke `Application.Run` that way when you run the host, the UI aspect and background worker hosted services will be started

Comment: Genius!! Invoking Application.Run on another hosted service worked like a charm, hahah

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution by Nkosi, on comments:

> Make another hosted service to invoke `Application.Run` that way when you run the host, the UI aspect and background worker hosted services will be started

```
class StartProgram : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    public StartProgram(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this._services = services;
    }
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run((AuthenticationForm)_services.GetService(typeof(AuthenticationForm)));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and the Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        await CreateHostBuilder().Build().RunAsync();
    }
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<LicenseControl>();
                services.AddHostedService<StartProgram>();

                #region ETC...
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done. Happy coding.

Comment: This did not work for me because other workers would not start (because Application.Run is blocking, I also have no form if that's relevant), so my `ExecuteAsync` method calls `await Task.Run(() => { /* setup application components */ Application.Run(); }, stoppingToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);` to defer that work to another thread so that the executable will move on to starting the next worker.

Answer (score 0):

I had to register the form in the service collection for it to work (after the calls to the services.AddHostedService().

services.AddScoped();